# OpenCV object detection using canny edges

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I'm working on a project where I detect obstacles through an Android smart phone, this application is meant to be a navigational guide for blind people.

I'm using OpenCV to detect canny edges in the video frame but am at a loss when coming to detecting an object. What I need is a method to extract/detect any object in a frame. I went though several examples but they were all on detecting specific objects like faces. Any input will be much appreciated since I'm new to image processing.

Comment: try background subtraction..

Comment: Buy a kinect camera instead, or start searching in the literature about "obstacle detection".